# Sublime plugin prints the results of the call into the comment

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, textmate, sublime-text-plugin

From 13:30 - 14:30, the narrator writes a comment and it runs the call instantly to output the results. Anyone know what plugin he is using for Textmate or Sublime text?

http://vimeo.com/24716767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for 
**SublimeRubyEval** Plugin.

You can read more about in in this blogpost:
http://kevinthompson.info/blog/2013/02/07/execute-ruby-code-inside-of-sublime-text.html

Comment: You are frikkin beautiful!